# Image analysis java fails to create output

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I am performing an image analysis.

I have 1 input image

```
    for(int i=0; i<height; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<width; j++){                              //do first set of steps
           Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(j, i));
           int red = .....
           int green = .....
           int blue = ....
           Color newColor = new Color(red,green,blue);
           image.setRGB(j,i,newColor.getRGB());
        }
     }

     for(int i=0; i<height; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<width; j++){                              //do second set of steps
           Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(j, i));
           int red = .....
           int green = .....
           int blue = ....
           Color newColor = new Color(red,green,blue);
           image.setRGB(j,i,newColor.getRGB());
        }
     }

     File ouptut = new File("output.jpg");
     ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", ouptut);
```

but the problem is it wont create when I use those 2 sets of steps.
but when 2nd set is neglected, it creates an image.

There is no error in compilation. Why does this happen? What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

So, the steps were the culprit.  I checked them and it is so helpful to place

```
catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly went wrong between the first and second steps?  I'm lost.